# Visual Studio Code: multi-column editor layout

Tags: visual-studio-code

When switching to a multi-column layout in VS Code (View > Editor Layout > Two Columns /  `workbench.action.editorLayoutTwoColumns`), is there a way to make the new column split at the currently active file, so that open editors to the right of the current file are put into the new column/group, rather than the new column being empty?

By way of example:

Here I have 4 open editors

[image]

When I open a second column, it is empty:

[image]

But I'm wondering if there is a way that to get the following at the point of using a multi-column view (relative to the active file I have open at the time):

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a visual reference of expectations, or be more descriptive of what you mean by `open editors to the right` please

Comment: Thanks @soulshined, I've added pictures.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Great question. I don’t think there is but interested to see what people have in mind without extensions

Comment: If you can't find an extension that does this, it's worth creating a feature request on their github, I know IntelliJ supports this feature (or at least one that closes all editors to the right or left) so it's possible others would look for this as well

Comment: @soulshined what extension are you speaking about? Is that possible to send commands to pycharm to open specific file on the left slice half and another file on the right half?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this shortcut can do that:

shortcut: View:Move Editor into next group

I set the keybinding with "shift+command+left arrow"

[image]

There are 4 open editors and the active one is command.md:

[image]

I press the shortcut I set, it looks like this:

[image]

The active editor is open in the second column at a time.

Hope this information is useful.